# convert scientific notation bash script

Tags: bash, decimal

I have a awk script that grabs numbers that I want. But the problem is they are in this kind of format: 1.8200E+02

In bash script this decimal notation is not supported so I was wonering anyone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My last answer was wrong, sorry about that. You can use printf for this:

```
printf '%.0f' 1.8200E+02
182
```

Comment: I think he meant the "scientific notation."

Comment: Haha, not my day. I pasted the wrong test. Please see the edited version.

Comment: it works for me now. for some cases I am trimming remaining decimals ie. 178.34 -> 178 but still doing the job that I was looking for. thx

Comment: does anyone help me with converting 178.34 in to 17834? I now need the extra numbers to compare

Comment: In my bash I must add LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  before printf. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845997/unexplicable-error-in-bash-printf-command-inside-a-script-returns-invalid-numb)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a better solution...

```
number=1.8200E+02
python -c "print float('$number')"
```