# printf command inside a script returns "invalid number"

Tags: bash, printf

I can't get `printf` to print a variable with the %e descriptor in a bash script. It would just say

```
#!/bin/bash
a=14.9
printf %e 14.9;
```

I know this is likely a very easy question, but I'm fairly new to bash and always used `echo`. Plus I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

---

when run i get

```
$ ./test.text
./test.text: line 3: printf: 14.9: invalid number
0,000000
```

therefore my problem is the locale variable LC_NUMERIC: it is set so that i use commas as decimal separators. Indeed, it is set to an european localization:

```
$ locale | grep NUM
LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.UTF-8"
```

I thought I set it to en_US.UTF-8, but evidently I didn't. Now the problem switches to find how to set my locale variable. Simply using

```
$ LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

won't work.

Comment: What do you get? Works fine over here...

Comment: While the code works fine here (result 1.490000e+01), this page http://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples indicates that the %e could/should be placed inside quotes. I.e printf "%e" 14.9;

Comment: @enhzflep: thankyou, but the problem's not that. You don't need to put arguments of printf in double quotes, unless the arguments themselves do not need it to. Besides it works without them anyway.

I can set the variable with

    $export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

but this is nonpermanent.
How can i make it permanent? I run Cygwin.

Comment: Try setting `LC_NUMERIC="C"`.

Comment: @Axel: But he wants `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @Keith: He wants to use a period as decimal separator, and that's what "C" does. In contrast to all other locales, you can be sure "C" is always installed.

Comment: @Axel: Thanks, en_US.UTF-8 works fine, the problem is that it is not permanent. If I start a new shell this is not going to stay the way I want.

I can set it again at every new script I launch, but I'd rather find a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Axel: The `"C"` locale doesn't handle UTF-8, which could be important for someone in Italy (accented characters), and he's already said he that setting it temporarily works for him.

Comment: Ok. So to make the change permanent, set the locale in your profile. I don't have cygwin installed, so I cannot tell you where the file is. But why don't you just set it in your script?

Comment: @KeithThompson: I haven't tried yet, but would that really be an issue when just setting LC_NUMERIC (and not the other LC_XXX)?

Comment: @Axel: Hmm, good point, probably not. (I set `$LC_COLLATE` to `"C"` myself.) FWIW, I have Cygwin and it sets everything to `"C.UTF-8"` by default. Maybe the OP's Cygwin installation inherited its locale settings from Windows.

Comment: @Axel: editing the script everytime doesn't look like good programming to me, and I can easily forget. Setting it once and for all on the other hand is much more practical (provided you realize how to do it of course :-)
KeithThompson: I believe Axel's right, accent would not be influenced from LC_NUMERIC.

Thankyou both anyway. :-)

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi: I think it's the other way round: If you set LC_NUMERIC in your script, your script will work regardless of the system's locale. If you do not set it, you have to change your system just to make some scripts work. At least you should have to change your script only once.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This:

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" printf %e 14.9
```

sets `$LC_NUMERIC` only for the duration of that one command.

This:

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

sets `$LC_NUMERIC` only for the duration of the current shell process.

If you add

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

to your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`, it will set `$LC_NUMERIC` for all bash shells you launch.

Look for existing code that sets `$LC_NUMERIC` in your `.bashrc` or other shell startup files.

**UPDATE:**

If the `$LC_NUMERIC` environment variable is not set, the `LC_NUMERIC` locale setting can be set from the `$LANG` or `$LC_ALL`. Check your environment variable settings as well as the output of the `locale` command. `$LC_ALL` overrides `$LC_NUMERIC`, and `$LC_NUMERIC` overrides `$LANG`. `man locale` and/or `man 7 locale` for details.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a locale problem, and it wasn't expecting a period. Try:

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" printf %e 14.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this error and found this page.  In my case, it was 100% pilot error.

```
month=2
printf "%02d" month
```

it should be

```
printf "%02d" "${month}"
```

or more simply

```
printf "%02d" $month
```