# How to use printf to print percentages without leading zeros? (.43)

Tags: bash

This is how I get the percentage:

```
 perc=$(echo "scale=2; ($prop*100)/$total" | bc)
```

This is how I print it

```
printf '%.2f\n' "$perc"
```

However I get an error for every number even though the format should be correct.

The error I'm getting:

```
line 34: printf: 1.23: invalid number
line 52: printf: .43: invalid number
```

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I googled for the answer and this should work. Thanks

Comment: This has to do with the locales. `printf '%0.2f\n' 23,45` should work. Check [Unexplicable error in bash: printf command inside a script returns “invalid number”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12845997/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui This was the case, thanks. However now that I've used the english locale I have the leading zeros. Is there a way to not include leading zeros with printf?

Comment: `,43` is not a number, so [`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) does not have any option to print things like this. What you can do is to pipe to another tool so that the first character gets removed: ---> `printf '%0.2f\n' 000,45 | cut -c2-` returns `,45`.

Comment: @fedorqui I actually had numbers in .33 form, but when I format it with %f,  it adds leading zeros. I just formatted them as strings (%s) because I'm using them in strings anyways.

Comment: @mythic, can you please add a summary of the solution as an answer and accept it, for the next people to get help out of your question as well? thanks in advance